# Where did the "E" in Salesforce go?

Tags: bug, status-completed

To whom should I reach to fix it?

[image]

Looks like SVG is a bit problematic
SVG URL : https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/salesforce/img/logo.svg?v=b2886f87beec

[image]

Comment: I make it as a problem in the primary.css with the width on `#hlogo a`.

Comment: Yeah.. making width as 320px solves it

Comment: I think we need someone from the community team onto this! Will reach out

Comment: Also related: [SALESFORCE me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpZWL.png) (who? me???) on the **meta**...

Comment: @MattLacey actually a CM can't help in this, programmer is needed to fix the code.

Comment: Same here. W7, Chrome & IE11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In building a new unified theme for Salesforce, we had to replace the original logo.svg. The new logo.svg has different dimensions and didn't account for the fixed dimensions in the old theme. This has been fixed.

It'll go out in the next build. Thanks for reporting!